# Helper loses parent context when wrapped in a custom block

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have a block of Handlebars that was rendering fine until I wrapped it in a custom block. Specifically there is a call to the parent context to get the `Currency` type. Bear in mind that this Handlebars block is wrapped in an `each`:

```
{{#each this.SubscriptionOptions.MonthlySubscriptions}}
```

So clearly I know where the problem is, I'm just not sure how to solve it.

Here is the block of Handlebars:

```
<p class="lead" style="font-size:40px">
  {{#ifGreaterThanZero PricePerBillingPeriod}}
    <strong>{{currency ../Currency}}{{priceFormat PricePerBillingPeriod}}</strong>
  {{else}}
    <strong>FREE</strong>
  {{/ifGreaterThanZero}}
</p>
```

The piece that is **now failing** is this:

```
{{currency ../Currency}}
```

Here is the `ifGreaterThanZero` helper code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifGreaterThanZero', function(value, options) {
  var intVal = parseInt(value);
  if (intVal) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

I took a look at `this`, and it is in fact the subscription option itself, so it contains the `PricePerBillingPeriod` for example.

The question is, how do I get it so that reaching the parent context works again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. You have to go up one more level. It's not necessarily *parent context* in the object sense, it's *helper parent context* and so the deeper you go, it's moving up the stack like a directory structure.

The new code looks like this:

```
<strong>{{currency ../../Currency}}{{priceFormat PricePerBillingPeriod}}</strong>
```